# When do we use setExperimentalOptions in selenium chrome options?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can someone Please explain me the last two lines of code.I have searched many sites for the answer but there is no clear explanation.

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
        options.setExperimentalOptions("prefs", chromePrefs);
```

Comment: according to https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html. Sets an experimental option. Useful for new ChromeDriver options not yet exposed through the ChromeOptions API.

Comment: For example to disable java script!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sets an experimental option. Useful for new ChromeDriver options not yet exposed through the [ChromeOptions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) API.

It basically allows us to test particular feature before it gets released from Chrome Developers.

Also check- An example is given in this [link](http://www.awesome-testing.com/2016/02/selenium-browser-capabilities-explained.html)